# Como pegar toas as soma de 'SUM'

Tags: sql, oracle

> Boa noite pessoal, gostaria de realizar uma soma com os 3 (SUM CASE) abaixo.

`SELECT
     SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qtdDba,
     SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qtdDev,
     SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qtdAnalista
     /*Porem com esse sum abaixo nao soma os 3 valores acima, tem alguma maneira 
     de somar esses 3 valores sem utilizar subselect*/
     SUM(1) as totalSum
FROM
    TABELA........`

Comment: Seu CASE não me parece funcional...

Comment: Seu case está funcionando? precisa detalhar melhor o problema com detalhes no enunciado. veja em exemplo de case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91262/7

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você queira somar os valores dessa forma:

```
SELECT

 SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
 SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
 SUM(CASE WHEN (a==b 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

 /*Porem com esse sum abaixo nao soma os 3 valores acima, tem alguma maneira 
 de somar esses 3 valores sem utilizar subselect*/
 SUM(1) as totalSum
FROM
    TABELA........
```